# Small tire rubber split

Tags: tires, repair, safety

there is a small slit/tear on my rear tire sidewalk near the rim.  I don't think it from hitting a curb.  Wanted to know if it's just cosmetic or info should have it replaced.

Would like to add picture if possible.
[image: tire cut]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a defect to me. The outer rubber tread appears to be separating from the carcass. Yes, the outer rubber goes around the outside of the carcass to meet at or near the bead. This eill only get worse.

Depending on how old the tire is, this could be warranted by the tire manufacturer.

In any case, **yes, replace**.

Comment: Thanks Paulster2.  Is it considered an emergency?!  I am currently out of town.  Do you think I can out about another 200 miles on it?  I would like to wait I till I got back to replace it.

Comment: If you need to wait, I doubt it's an issue, but you'll want to keep a close eye on it. Ensure the tire pressure is up to snuff. Low tires generate a lot of heat which will exacerbate this issue and make it fail quicker. Also, try not too go too fast. As it's on the back, the issue is lessened. Just take care of it.